# Exponential Generating Function Fun

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

Given the recurrence relation of $a_n = a_{n-1} + n$,  for $n \gt 0$, Where $a_0 = 1$.

I know the solution is: $a_n = \frac{1}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n + 1$.

I am not having troubles finding this solution, however, I am having troubles acquiring the solution by means of what the question is asking for.

I need to answer this question using only an **Exponential Generating Function**.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}\ .$$
Then
$$\eqalign{A(x)
  &=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_{n-1}+n)\frac{x^n}{n!}\cr
  &=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}
    +\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cr
  &=1+xe^x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\ .\cr}$$
Differentiating both sides leads to the differential equation
$$\frac{dA}{dx}-A=(x+1)e^x\ ,$$
and solving with the initial condition $A(0)=1$ gives
$$A=(1+x+\tfrac12x^2)e^x\ .$$
Extracting the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ gives the answer.

I'll leave you to fill in the working.

Comment: Thank you!  Much easier than I was making it out to be (as I am sure we all do at some point haha).  Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome!